# Is there any way to make it so that Python processing is performed even if the button is "Open New Tab" via Ajax

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax

I am trying to prevent the user from moving to the manager class target link by using Ajax, but I am facing a problem that if I right-click to open a new tab or open in a new window, the user can move to the target link.

By the way, the JS is written as follows, and when the button is pressed, Ajax is activated.

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    const url = '//login?id=', userId);

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  type: 'GET',
  async: false,
})
  .then(function (data) {
    const nextUrl = data.url;

    if (transferUrl) {
      location.href = nextUrl;
    } else {
      alert('No Authorization');
    }
  })
  .catch(function () {
    alert('Failed');
  });
```

The button HTML is written as follows.

```
<a id="button" href="/admin/top.html">
   <img id="toplnk" src="/images/login/a.png" onmouseover="this.src='/images/login/b.png'" onmouseout="this.src='/images/login/c.png'" alt="page">
</a>
```

The Python code that is sent and processed by Ajax is as follows.

```
def check_user(self, request):
  user_id = request.GET.get(key='id')
  user = User.objects.all().filter(Q(UserId__exact=user_id), condition_role)
  if user.count() == 0:
     url = ""
  else:
     url = '/admin/top.html'
  json_data = {'url': url}
  return Response(json_data)
```

Is there any way to make it so that Python processing is performed even if the button is "Open New Tab" via Ajax as shown above?

Comment: Sounds like you were trying to implement a "security by obscurity" measure, which is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a couple of solutions, you need to decide which one would suit your usecase.

1. You can remove anchor tag href and programmatically navigate to the link using window.location(), this will block the "open in new tab" option. If you do not require it, you can go with this solution.
2. If you require open in new tab to be there as an option, then I believe you need to run your ajax on the load of the page you are navigating to, alongwith conditions if you do not want to run this every time on that page. This is typically a usecase similar to running a function on ComponentMount or useEffect in React JS.